# Swift function returns Void return type from other function

Tags: swift, return, void

I came across Swift code something like this today. The author is long gone.

```
func doSomething(string: String) {

    ...

    if doMore(string: String) != nil {
        return update(using: string)
    }

    ...
}

func udpate(using: String) {

    //does some stuff

}
```

Notice that `doSomething()` does not return a value. Nor does `update()`. At least not explicitly. As it says in the docs, Swift functions that don't return a value actually do. They return Void.

Therefore `return update(using: string)` is legal syntax. `update()` returns `Void` and so does `doSomething()` so the compiler doesn't complain and it runs.

Here's my question. Is `return update(using: string)` exploiting some handy side effect or is it exactly the same as this?

```
update(using: string)
return
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The two snippets of code are equivalent.

Comment: It’s entirely a matter of style. It _is_ employing a handy side effect in the sense that the call to `update` is a side effect (because it returns nothing useful). But more generally the stylistic point is to say “if you get here, exit, having called `update`” in one line, making the exit very explicit by saying it immediately. It isn’t uncommon, but personally I don’t do it much.

Comment: Thanks. In general I prefer clarity over brevity, especially obscure brevity. So, yeah, I can't see myself using that particular form of `return`. In fact, I'm going to add this example to our Swift Best Practices and suggest avoiding it. Not because it's inherently bad. I'm reasonably familiar with most Swift syntax but this obscure form of `return` gave me pause. I spent time looking through the docs, I had to test it myself and take the time to formulate this question. Better to use that time to continue with the bug chase I was on!